# How to Automatically pull printer settings from printer into the print queue?

Tags: printing

Is there a way to automate (trigger) the queue properties -> configuration -> 'Update Now-Ask Printer' button?  I need to pull configuration information directly from the printer itself into the queue.  Driver is Lexmark Universal v2 XL if that matters... I think PrintUI only triggers specifics if they are in the registry.  Not sure if Printui can be used? (Win server 2008 r2, 32bit)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have a situation where I need to do this on about 20,000 printers and I'm doing research while waiting on guidance from Lexmark.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a way to automatically do this, the three corresponding checkbox registry keys under configuration are DCDPrtPropOK (On Properties Open), OnPortChange and UpdateConfigurationFromPrinter.  Values are 1 – ON, or 0 – OFF.  Actual location is (computer\HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print(drivername)\PrinterDriverData.

Essentially, we need to change DCDPrtPropOK to 1, then run this command:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /p /n "Lexmark Universal v2 XL”
```

as a non adm (users if the have the rights) command prompt to trigger Printer Properties.  This should force the printer to open the Printer Properties window, and ask the printers for the settings.

Comment: Good try. I'm not seeing DCDPrtProOK having the desired effect though. When I toggle "On Properties open" that registry value doesn't change.   The printui call is clever but it goes modal and then has to be closed.

Comment: Have you tried looking into getting settings via SNMP?